# How to escape ^ character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, substring

For a message in a specific message format (HL7) I'm trying to escape the `^` sign. So the string `abc^def^ghi` should become `abc\^def\^ghi`

I tried the following ways:

```
> "abc^def^ghi".replace("^", "\^");
'abc^def^ghi'
> "abc^def^ghi".replace("^", "\\^");
'abc\\^def^ghi'
> "abc^def^ghi".replace("^", "\\\^");
'abc\\^def^ghi'
> "abc^def^ghi".replace("\^", "\\\^");
'abc\\^def^ghi'
> "abc^def^ghi".replace("\\^", "\\\^");
'abc^def^ghi'
> "abc^def^ghi".replace(/^/g, "\\\^");
'\\^abc^def^ghi'
> "abc^def^ghi".replace(/\^/g, "\\\^");
'abc\\^def\\^ghi'
> "abc^def^ghi".replace(/\^/g, "\\^");
'abc\\^def\\^ghi'
> "abc^def^ghi".replace(/\^/g, "\^");
'abc^def^ghi'
> "abc^def^ghi".replace(/\\^/g, "\\\^");
'abc^def^ghi'
```

As you can see, none of them work as I want them to. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: You already have it `"abc^def^ghi".replace(/\^/g, "\\^");` but showing incorrect output.

Comment: Which REPL did you use for this test?

Comment: @anubhava! I used the node repl in the terminal, but I now see it does give the right output in the Chromium console. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"abc^def^ghi".replace(/\^/g, "\\\^")
```

You have to escape `^` in the regex, because it's a special character.